# Table with fixed first column, and fixed headers, without position sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, fixed

I'm looking for a way to create this table functionality, using html/css/js:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130829032141/http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/css_size.html

I need the first column to be fixed when the table is scrolled horizontally, but the first column should scroll vertically when the table is scrolled vertically.

The table header of the first column should be fixed when scrolled horizontally, but the other headers need to scroll horizontally if the table is scrolled horizontally, but should remain fixed at the top if the table is scrolled vertically.

I found one example of how to do this, but it used position: sticky, which is not working for me because I am using extjs and there are so many rendered elements with overflow properties, I cannot get sticky to work.

I've got the first row fixed part working, but I can't get the headers to work. I also can't figure out how to get the horizontal scroll bar to be at the bottom of what is visible instead of the bottom of the container. I'm hoping to get a fiddle working and then transfer that to extjs:

```
<div id="#container">
  <div id="first-col">
  <div class="col-header">first col header</div>
  
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
  <div class="cell">first col element</div>
</div>

<div id="repeating-cols">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-header">repeat col header</div>
      
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
      <div class="cell">first col element</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-col {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -43px;
  left: 0;
}

.col-header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
}

.cell {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
}

#repeating-cols {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.col {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgy76tn1/

Comment: So, you want the header to stay fixed, right? And the left header too?

Comment: The header for the first column should be completely fixed. The headers for the repeating columns should scroll horizontally with the table contents, but remain fixed if the table contents are scrolled vertically. I'll edit the question to make this clear

Comment: Ahh, then you can use `position:fixed` to your div containing headers and a `z-indez:999`

Comment: I thought about that but then everything is positioned to the viewport right? so I couldn't have anything above the table? I could be wrong, I'm open to anything that could work